# Two textviews on listview aligend right

Tags: android

I wanted 2 textviews on my listview that I want to one of them has right align and another align center but all of them aligend left !!! my listview xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#ffffff"
  android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_subject"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
    android:textSize="13sp"   
    android:textStyle="bold" />

  <LinearLayout 
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal">    

  <ImageView 
    android:id="@+id/iv_pic"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:contentDescription="ads"/>

   <TextView 
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:id="@+id/tv_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

this code worked successfully but when compiler build the application and I want to touch one row at list view in fact when my finger is at list view color of row should be change, but because I had to set width match_parent it cover the entire screen.
how can I make this the output that I want and when my finger is on the selected row user see the color of the row has changed.

Comment: You question is not very clear. Can you explain again what is happening and what is expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete `android:background="#ffffff"`. If you want change color - set it to ListView.